# Velocity Verlet integration producing massive results python

Tags: python, physics

As part of a vector class/ "physics engine" I am making, I am trying to implement a velocity verlet algorithm to solve Newton's equations of motion. However, the algorithm that I have implemented is producing massive values, as you can see below. i have tried what I believe to be every option on my own, and was wondering if someone could help. Thanks.

```
Xpos = 0
OldPos = 1
dt = 0.02
Xaccel = 9.81

def doVerletX(currentPos, oldPos, accel, dt):
    newPos = (currentPos + (currentPos-oldPos) + (accel*dt*dt))
    return newPos

for a in range (1,10,1):
    newPos = doVerletX(Xpos,OldPos,dt,Xaccel)
    print(newPos)
    OldPos = Xpos
    dt+=dt
```

The output to the above code was:

```
0.9247220000000003
3.8494440000000005
7.698888000000001
15.397776000000002
30.795552000000004
61.59110400000001
123.18220800000002
246.36441600000003
492.72883200000007
```

I know that this is obviously wrong and was wondering what to do to fix it?

Comment: `dt` is delta t? why are you doing `dt+=dt`? Also I think your parameter are in wrong order when calling the funciton. In function definition `dt` is 4th argument, during call you are passing `dt` as 3rd argument.

Answer (score 1):

Already mentioned was the `dt+=dt` problem that should be `t+=dt`.

In the time propagation, you also need to shift the `newPos` value to `Xpos`.

The interface definition for `doVerlet` has `dt` as last argument, you have to use it that way also in the function call.

```
Xpos = 0
OldPos = 1
t=0
dt = 0.02
Xaccel = 9.81

def doVerletX(currentPos, oldPos, accel, dt):
    newPos = (currentPos + (currentPos-oldPos) + (accel*dt*dt))
    return newPos

for a in range (1,10,1):
    newPos = doVerletX(Xpos,OldPos,Xaccel,dt)
    t+=dt    
    print(t,newPos)
    OldPos, Xpos = Xpos, newPos
```

Using that code gives the result

```
(0.02, -0.996076)
(0.04, -1.988228)
(0.06, -2.976456)
(0.08, -3.960760)
(0.10, -4.941140)
(0.12, -5.917596)
(0.14, -6.890128)
(0.16, -7.858736)
(0.18, -8.823420)
```

which is believable as the initial velocity is `-50 m/s` and the acceleration towards the positive.

---

To get the correct initial velocity and thus exact solution one would have to solve

```
x(t)=x0+v0*t+0.5*g*t^2
```

for `v0` at `t=-0.02` using `x(0)=x0=0` and `x(-0.02)=1` giving

```
v0=-(1-0.02^2/2*9.81)/0.02=-49.9019  and  x(0.18)=-8.82342
```

which is exactly the value computed above. This is as it should be with an order 2 method.

Comment: In real life, that object would have traveled -9 units but the verlet algorithm here says-8.82 and they is an error of approximately 2% and so I was wondering if this error would cumulatively grow, and if so make the simulation horrifically inaccurate as the error of 2% is after only 10 iterations.

Comment: The formula for the position is `x(t)=-50*t+0.5*9.81*t^2` which at `t=0.18` gives `-8.841078` which is not that far off.

Comment: How does the velocity equal -50, because when you do currentPos - oldPos you are not dividing by dt. Also, what does the OldPos, Xpos = Xpos, newPos part mean (I know you are equating things, but I am not sure which things).

Comment: `(x(0)-x(-0.02))/0.02 = -50`. Of course that is only an estimate by the mean value. I added the completely exact computation of the exact solution to the answer.